# SQLite-Python "executemany()" not executing to the database

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to get this program to store the values for a persons firstname and surname in a database. The database is called Class and the table inside it that I am trying to insert data into is called Names. 
I have tried to rearrange this several times and removed it from its try loop to try diagnose the issue. Thanks in advance. I will help the best I can :)

```
new_first,new_surname = str(input("Firstname:\t")), str(input("Surname:\t"))
new_name = [new_surname, new_first]
print(new_name)
c.executemany("INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?,?)", new_name)
```

The error message I keep getting is:
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 7 supplied.

Comment: Why are you using `executemany()`? That's to be used when you want to execute the same SQL statement for multiple sets of parameters, but you have *just one*.

Comment: OFCOURSE!!! I actually don't know why I kept it as executemany. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `cursor.executemany()`, use `cursor.execute()`:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?,?)", new_name)
```

`executemany()` should be used for *multiple rows of data*, but you have just one.

The error is caused by the `executemany()` method treating `new_surname` as a row by itself, and since a string is iterable an attempt is made to use every individual character from that string as a parameter. A string length of 7 would give you 7 parameters, and that doesn't match the 2 in the SQL statement.

If you *do* have many rows, then each row would have to consist of a last and first name value for the two parameters:

```
new_names = [
    [new_surname, new_first],
    ['another surname', 'another first name'],
    # ...
]
c.executemany("INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?,?)", new_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

`executemany()` expects *many* items, as the name suggests.

That means a list of lists, or any similar data structure. You give it only one item.

```
new_first, new_surname = str(input("Firstname:\t")), str(input("Surname:\t"))
new_name = [[new_surname, new_first]]

c.executemany("INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?,?)", new_name)
```

or use `execute` if you only have one item

```
new_first, new_surname = str(input("Firstname:\t")), str(input("Surname:\t"))
new_name = [new_surname, new_first]

c.execute("INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?,?)", new_name)
```